# Qwt: scaling the axis - ticks' labels repeat themselves

Tags: scale, precision, label, qwt

I'm working on a QwtPlot - I have a regular time scale on X axis and a custom y scale with discrete values

The problem is that when I'm zooming the discrete Axis (it has major ticks only) with a magnifier, the ticks on the scale start repeating themselves and instead of getting 
e.g. 2 ticks "0" and "1" I'm getting 4 ticks "0", "0", "1", "1" (or more, depends on the zoom). So because the divider can't divide the values, it just repeats them.

No idea what function or object to use/reimplement to make the scale stop drawing additional divisions (and btw also additional grid lines). Just stopping the magnifier from magnifying too much isn't the right answer since I want it to magnify more.

What I did to my discrete y axis (in CPlot inheriting QwtPlot) is:

> ```
> QList<double> ticks;
> for(int i=0; i<visualisation->getPIDs().size();i++)
> {
>     ticks.append(i);
> }
> QwtScaleDiv* div=new QwtScaleDiv(0,visualisation->getPIDs().size()-1);
> div->setTicks(QwtScaleDiv::MajorTick, ticks);
> discreteScale=new CDiscreteScaleDraw;
> discreteScale->setLUT(visualisation->getPIDs());
> setAxisScaleDraw(QwtPlot::yLeft, discreteScale);
> setAxisMaxMinor(QwtPlot::yLeft,0);
> this->setAxisAutoScale(QwtPlot::yLeft, 0);
> ```

PS. On my time scale I have a similar problem, but this is the case of precision - when zooming in I would like to get the precision of 123,456.789 and I get 123,456.78 (and then the labels get doubled, tripled etc again). I would also like to remove the coma that QwtScaleDraw puts there so that I would get 123456.789, but the most important thing is getting rid of repeating labels.

Answer (score 1):

The significance of a double is more than 6 but not endless, so without limiting the magnifier you will run sooner or later into this issue.

The double to string conversion is done using QLocale::toString() with its default parameter values ( 'g', 6 ). If you want to use different values you have to overload by implementing CDiscreteScaleDraw::label().

Concerning the ",': guess this is because of the NumberOptions of your locale. Try to change them using QLocale::setNumberOptions().

Comment: Thank you very much - I managed to changed the precision on the time scale the way I wanted to (I had no idea about QLocale)

But I still have problem with the discrete scale. Look at this sceenshot:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=a452rc&s=5#.UoI_GoZhauY

I don't want to have all that repeated values and the grid to be so "dense"... can you somehow stop the scale from adding unnecessary major ticks?